# Xtable: printing table does not fit to left of the document (using center and textwidth)

Tags: r, latex, sweave, pdflatex

[ANSWERED | CLOSED]

my task is to create a document with tables which have to be formatted. The first table is justified on the right and left side. Therefore the table is fitted and centered. But the left side of the table doesnt fit to the text at the top of the document. The right I think is OK.

The code is:
table.csv:

```
 ,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
C1,1.00%,200.00%,1.00%,1.00%,1.00%,-18.90%,-38.80%,-58.70%,-78.60%,-98.50%
C2,1.00%,2.00%,1.00%,1.00%,1.00%,0.90%,0.80%,0.70%,0.60%,0.50%
C3,11.00%,22.00%,11.00%,11.00%,11.00%,9.90%,8.80%,7.70%,6.60%,5.50%
C4,1,2,1,1,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5
C5,1,2,3,1,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5
```

Sweave.Rnw:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Header und Footer
\usepackage{scrpage2} \pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadfoot 
%\ohead{\includegraphics[width=10mm]{}}
\ihead{Header}
\ifoot{\today} 
\setheadtopline{0mm}
\setheadsepline{0.2mm}
\setfootsepline{0.2mm}
\setfootbotline{0pt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=15mm,right=15mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, headsep=15mm} 

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTe xtTextTextTexTexttT extTextTextTextTextTextTex tTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTe xtTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextT extTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextT extTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextT extTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTe xtTextTextTextTextTextTextTe xtTextTextTextTextTextTextTextT extTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTe xtTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTex tTextTextv TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
\\\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}
\underline{Table heading:}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
<<RR, echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
options(xtable.floating=FALSE)

t <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T, na.strings = c(""), sep = ",")

xT <- xtable(t)
print(xT, caption.placement = "top", include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE)
@
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Best regards

Comment: You need to use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{%` - note the `%` sign. As reference, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)

Comment: Vielen Dank :D und viele Grüße
\\
[Closed]